# ¿ Modo correcto de copiar una clase que internamente contiene una union anónima?

Tags: c++, c++11

Supongamos que tengo esta clase:

```
#include <string.h>

class MyClass {
private:
  union {
    ::std::string string_;
    int int_;
    float float_;
  };

public:
  MyClass( const MyClass &o ) noexcept : MyClass( ) {
    memcpy( this, &o, sizeof( *this ) );
  }
};
```

Lo anterior es un *ejemplo hipotético*; no se muestra ninguna *lógica de control*, pero la clase real **si** la tiene.

El tema es que **necesito** implementar mi propio *constructor copia* (para realizar esa lógica de control), por lo que no puedo usar el constructor por defecto. Como se ve, utilizo el *arcaico* `memcpy( )` para copiar los datos de la clase.

¿ Esta es la forma correcta de hacerlo ? ¿ No tiene C++ una *forma C++ de hacer las cosas* para estos menesteres ? Para C++11.

#### EDITO

Por motivos varios, me interesa no tener demasiadas dependencias de compilación, por lo que usar `boost` u otras herramientas de terceros queda descartado. Se supone que será una *pequeña* utilidad. En cualquier caso, siempre puedo seguir usando `memcpy( )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este tema es mucho más complejo de lo que parece, las uniones en C++ son un vestigio de C que abren la puerta a muchos [comportamientos indefinidos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido) (CI), para intentar evitar varios de estos CI se aplican sobre las uniones una serie de restricciones.

Una de las restricciones se relaciona con el uso de objetos no triviales como miembros de las uniones, de hecho, [el ejemplo del estándar es idéntico a tu caso](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 9.5 Uniones
>
> 2. Una unión puede tener funciones miembro (incluyendo constructores y destructores), pero no funciones virtuales. Una unión no debe tener clases base. Una unión no debe ser usada como clase base. Si una unión contiene un miembro no estático de tipo referencia, el programa estará mal formado [ *Nota:* **Si cualquiera de los miembros no estáticos de una unión tiene un constructor por defecto no trivial, constructor de copia, constructor de movimiento, operador de copia-asignación, operador de movimiento-asignación o destructor, la correspondiente función miembro de la unión debe ser proveída por el usuario** o será borrada implícitamente para la unión —*fin de la nota*]
> 3. [ *Ejemplo:* Consideremos la siguiente unión:
>
>    ```
>    union U {
>        int i;
>        float f;
>        std::string s;
>      };
>    ```
>
>    **Dado que `std::string` declara versiones no triviales de todas las funciones miembro especiales, `U` tendrá constructor por defecto, constructor de copia/movimiento, operador de copia-asignación/movimiento y destructor implícitamente borrados**. Para usar `U` alguna o todas estas funciones miembro deberán ser proveídas. —*fin del ejemplo*]

Hemos identificado un problema, tu unión carece de las funciones miembro necesarias para ser usada; pero dado que es una función anónima no se le pueden crear constructor por defecto, **constructor de copia** o destructor.

> El tema es que **necesito** implementar mi propio *constructor copia* (para realizar esa lógica de control), por lo que no puedo usar el constructor por defecto. Como se ve, utilizo el *arcaico* `memcpy( )` para copiar los datos de la clase.

Esto es una terrible idea, por varios motivos:

- Hacer una copia bit-a-bit de objetos complejos como `std::string` desencadena CI; tras hacer el `std::memcpy` de dos `std::string` tienes virtualmente el objeto dos veces, cuando una de las copias fallezca, llamará al destructor y borrará la memoria que **ambas** copias están usando; la copia que aún sigue viva estará usando memoria borrada e intentará borrar de nuevo dicha memoria ya borrada al finalizar su ciclo de vida.
- En C++ las uniones tienen un (y sólo un) miembro activo (traducción y resaltado míos):

  > #### 9.5 Uniones
  >
  > 1. **En una unión, como mucho uno de los miembros no estáticos puede estar activo en cualquier momento**, esto es, el valor de como mucho uno de los miembros no estáticos puede ser guardado en una unión en cualquier momento. [...]

Usar el miembro inactivo de una unión desencadena CI. Por desgracia el estándar de C++ no es muy claro al respecto de esto ni de cómo se activa un miembro de una unión. `std::memcpy` no tiene en cuenta esto, desencadenando CI.

#### Conclusión

El código que buscas no existe en C++, usando uniones anónimas eliminas la posibilidad de crear funciones miembro que controlan la construcción de los elementos y dichas funciones son requeridas para crear una unión con elementos no triviales. Puedes esquivar esta restricción llamando al destructor de `std::string` explícitamente en `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    using string = std::string;
    union {
        string string;
        int int_;
        float float_;
    };

    ~MyClass() {string_.~string();};
};
```

Pero esto sólo será válido si y sólo si el objeto `MyClass::string_` está activo en el momento de la destrucción de la instancia de `MyClass`.

En cuanto a la inicialización (tu ejemplo no incluye el constructor por defecto de `MyClass`) puedes añadir un inicializador por defecto a uno (y sólo uno) de los miembros de la unión:

```
union {
    string string_ = {};
    int int_;
    float float_;
};
```

Pero esto activará dicho miembro en el constructor por defecto, haciendo que el uso del resto de miembros desencadene CI.

Respecto a la copia, sucederá igual. Puedes añadir un constructor de copia pero no puedes estar seguro de estar copiando el miembro activo:

```
MyClass( const MyClass &o ) noexcept : string_{o.string_} {
}
```

Así pues, lo que pides no se puede hacer sin caer en CI.

Comment: ya te estaba yo echando de menos en esta pregunta

Comment: Te acepto la respuesta; es la única que lo deja claro: `El código que buscas no existe en C++`. Una pena, me hacia *ilu* :-/

Answer (score 0):

Si es una opción yo plantearía sustituir la unión anónima por [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/variant.html), disponible desde tiempos inmemoriales... anteriores a la versión 1.35:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

int main()
{
  boost::variant<int,std::string> test;

  test = 5;
  std::cout << test << '\n';

  test = "abcdef";
  std::cout << test << '\n';
}
```

Este cambio sería casi equivalente a darle un nombre a la unión... la ventaja es que esta clase evita lecturas erróneas:

```
int main()
{
  boost::variant<int,std::string> test;

   test = 5;

  std::cout << boost::get<int>(test); // ok
  std::cout << boost::get<std::string>(test); // error en tiempo de ejecucion
}
```

Además también permite saber qué tipo es el que tiene actualmente valor:

```
int main()
{
  auto lambda = [](boost::variant<int,std::string> const& var)
  {
    if( var.type() == typeid(int) )
    {
      int valor = boost::get<int>(var);
      std::cout << valor << '\n';
    }
    else if( var.type() == typeid(std::string) )
    {
      std::string valor = boost::get<std::string>(var);
      std::cout << valor << '\n';
    }
  };

  boost::variant<int,std::string> test;

  test = 5;
  lambda(test);

  test = "abcdef";
  lambda(test);
}
```

Otra ventaja de usar esta estructura es que, posteriormente, el código será facilmente portable a C++17 cambiando el espacio de nombres `boost` por `std`

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta (+1). No lo indicaba en la pregunta original (la he editado), pero no me interesa utilizar cosas mas allá de la librería estándar. No quiero tener que instalar *muchocientos* megas de la _boost_ solo para usar esto, que supuestamente será una *pequeña* utilidad. Y que conste que me enamoré de _boost_ cuando descubrí [`boost::intrusive`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/intrusive.html).

Comment: @Dolmenes Si estás con un compilador C++17, puedes usar std::variant

Comment: @asdasdasd ¡¡ Si hombre, si a duras penas me *medio-manejo* con el 11 !! Al final, lo dejaré como está, con `memcpy( )`. Tampoco es que sea importante, era por *curiosidad* (mi c++ es bajo/medio). O, si me siento especialmente inspirado, podría controlarlo con `#if __cplusplus__ ...`. A ver cuando lo termine, si los cambios no son excesivos ...

Answer (score -1):

```
MyClass(const MyClass &o) : float_(o.float_) { } // float_ u otro cualquiera.
```

Comment: ¿ Como se **seguro** el miembro de mayor tamaño ? ¿ Un `float`  ocupa mas *bytes* que una `::std::string` ?

Comment: No hace falta que sea el de mayor tamaño, cualquiera de ellos estará bien. (Cualquiera de ellos es una forma de referirse al mismo espacio en memoria)

Comment: Al menos en C++ lo que dices no es cierto [ejemplo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VjbeaRJggU7oFsKO). Con tu código únicamente se copian los bytes ocupados por la variable elegida en vez de toda la unión

Comment: @eferion En todo caso debí aclarar que sólo uno de los miembros es el activo, y que intentar leer cualquiera de los otros (como en tu ejemplo) es "undefined behavior".

Comment: El problema ahí sería identificar qué miembro hay que inicializar en cada momento... y eso no sería posible hacerlo dentro del apartado de inicializaciones (el que va detrás de los dos puntos `:`) sino que habría que hacerlo en el apartado del código de la función.

Comment: @eferion Sí, y si el miembro activo fuera la string, habría que destruirla primero antes de hacer activo a otro. Voto por std::variant, o una (Tagged union) [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union] (no me sale eso de poner un link...)

Comment: Es al reves... los corchetes con la etiqueta y los paréntesis para el enlace